# Copy-initialization of atomic variables in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, atomic, stdatomic

Can atomic variables in C++11 be initialized globally?

For example:

```cpp
std::atomic_int turnX = 5;
int main() {
    /* ... */
}
```

This fails with:

```
error: deleted function ‘std::atomic<int>::atomic(const std::atomic<int>&)’
```

Looking at `<atomic>`, it does give an idea that this is not allowed.
Am I correct in making a statement that atomic variables can be assigned values only from within a function?

Comment: Nearly a duplicate of [How to initialize a static std::atomic data member](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20453054/5740428)

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```cpp
std::atomic_int turnX(5);
```

This uses a `constexpr` constructor, so it should be constructed as [constant initialization](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.start.init#def:Constant_initialization) (i.e. at load time).

Comment: but why would `atomic_int turnX = 5;` not invoke that constructor ? Any quotes from the standard?

Comment: @smerlin: I imagine because it uses copy-initialisation. What might be happening is the `5` is being implicitly converted into an `atomic_int` and then `turnX` is copy-constructed from a non-`constexpr` object.

Answer (score 3):

`std::atomic` variable (since it is not copyable or movable) can only be initialized using direct-initialization.

`std::atomic_int turnX = 5;` will only compile and run on a C++17 compiler or higher. Explanation:

```
// Prior to C++17
std::atomic_int turnX = 5; // Copy initialization => Compilation error.
std::atomic_int turnX(5); // Direct initialization.
std::atomic_int turnX{ 5 }; // Direct initialization.
```

Prior to C++17, the copy-initialization `std::atomic_int turnX = 5;` would first construct a temporary `std::atomic_int` from 5 and then direct-initialize `turnX`  from that temporary. Without a move or copy constructor this would fail and so the line doesn't compile. `std::atomic_int turnX (5);` or `std::atomic_int turnX {5};` however, is directly initialized by a constructor call with 5 as argument.

```
// C++17 or higher
std::atomic_int turnX = 5; // Direct initialization.
std::atomic_int turnX(5); // Direct initialization.
std::atomic_int turnX{ 5 }; // Direct initialization.
```

In C++17 or higher, the temporary is no longer created. Instead, `turnX` is directly initialized by a constructor call with 5 as argument. So, there is no issue with `std::atomic_int` being not copyable or movable.