# How to initialize a static std::atomic data member

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, atomic, stdatomic

I would like to generate identifiers for a class named `order` in a thread-safe manner. The code below does not compile. I know that the atomic types do not have copy constructors, and I assume that explains why this code does not work.

Does anybody know a way to actually get this code to work? Is there an alternative approach?

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

class order {
public: 
    order() { id = c.fetch_add(1); }
    int id;
private:
    static std::atomic<int> c;
};

std::atomic<int> order::c = std::atomic<int>(0);

int main() {
    order *o1 = new order();
    order *o2 = new order();
    std::cout << o1->id << std::endl; // Expect 0
    std::cout << o2->id << std::endl; // Expect 1
}
```

Compiling the above results in the following error:

```
order.cpp:45:51: error: use of deleted function 
        ‘std::atomic<int>::atomic(const std::atomic<int>&)’
In file included from order.cpp:3:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/atomic:594:7: error: declared here
```

Comment: Related: [Copy-initialization of atomic variables in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6700795/5740428)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

> I know that the atomic types do not have copy constructors, and I assume that explains why this code does not work.

Yes, the error says that quite clearly.

> Does anybody know a way to actually get this code to work?

Instead of copy-initialising from a temporary, which requires an accessible copy constructor:

```
std::atomic<int> order::c = std::atomic<int>(0);
```

use direct-initialisation, which doesn't:

```
std::atomic<int> order::c(0);   // or {0} for a more C++11 experience
```

You should probably prefer that anyway, unless you enjoy reading unnecessarily verbose code.

Comment: In C++17 and later (at least with GCC) you can even write `std::atomic_int order::c = 0;`.  https://godbolt.org/z/TsGKzYG9e .  Of course at global scope, this is static storage, so `std::atomic<int> order::c;` was already sufficient to get a `0`.  (C11 had an `ATOMIC_VAR_INIT` but even then it wasn't needed, [removed in C17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/ATOMIC_VAR_INIT).  An all-zero object-representation is a valid state that's ready for use, and static storage always does that.)

Answer (score 34):

How about the definition

```
std::atomic<int> order::c{0}
```

Answer (score 6):

Also you can use `atomic_init`:

```
std::atomic<int> data;
std::atomic_init(&data, 0);
```

Comment: this would not be initialized during compilation?

Comment: Isn't static variable thread safe from c++11?
I see the ++11 tag up in the question.
So why do we need atomics on the first place? Why can't we just use regular int?

Comment: @anicicn A bit late, but the initialization of the static variable is guaranteed to only run once and is thread safe. After that, it's essentially just a regular int, i.e. not thread safe. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102125/is-local-static-variable-initialization-thread-safe-in-c11

Comment: @SergKryvonos: Correct, you can't put this at global scope.  You could put the `std::atomic_init(&data, 0);` at the top of `main`, but that's ugly and inefficient compared to just `std::atomic<int> data {};` (which also works in function scope).  Or for static storage like in the question, even just `std::atomic<int> data;` works; static storage is zero-initialized by default, and this is sufficient for `std::atomic` or C `_Atomic` to work correctly (C17 required that and deprecated [ATOMIC_VAR_INIT](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/ATOMIC_VAR_INIT)).

Answer (score 0):

Since `std::atomic_init` has been [deprecated in C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_init), here is a reimplementation which does not raise deprecation warnings, if you for some reason want to keep doing this.

```
static inline void sys_atomic_init(sys_atomic_t *ref, uint32_t value)
{
#ifdef __cplusplus
    // atomic_init is deprecated in C++20
    // use the equivalent definition from https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0883r2.pdf
    atomic_store_explicit(ref, value, std::memory_order_relaxed);
#else
    atomic_init(ref, value);
#endif
}
```

from https://github.com/skupperproject/skupper-router/blob/cfc8b4c6892dafc5dd0c86682b4db87a488f2451/include/qpid/dispatch/atomic.h#L41

Comment: Perhaps `#if defined(__cplusplus) && (__cplusplus < 202002L)` so your init is fully non-atomic in languages / versions that allow that without deprecation warnings.  Might avoid an extra store for space that was already initialized with `value`, e.g. if that value is `0` and the surrounding bytes are also being zeroed.  (Compilers don't optimize away atomic stores, so the relaxed store will run an asm instruction to do it.)  Not a big deal for `uint32_t` where all mainstream platforms can do that lock-free so it's cheap.